APM agent - trace id and span id is the same for all records consumed from kafka
When I start kafka via auto startup, tracing works correctly. When I start kafka manually (autoStartup = false), transaction never ends, goes infinitely.
    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 20_000)
    public void startKafka() {
        registry.start();
    }

Every kafka record belonging to the same trace, and finally causing OutOfMemoryError in production. I analyzed the problem and in my opinion the code that causes difference is here:
KafkaInstrumentationHeadersHelper.java. Method shouldWrapIterable returns true only when there is no active span, but span exists inside method annotated @Scheduled.
I reproduced error here:
https://github.com/matlewan/apm-agent-kafka
Clone project and run mvn clean test and see messages printed to console. Change autoStartup to true or uncomment disable_instrumentations=scheduled to see the difference.
Alternative solutions:

A. When I changed autoStartup=true , traceId and spanId are unique for every record, but I would like to have autoStartup=false for other reasons.
B. When I add APM property disable_instrumentations=scheduled , traceId and spanId are unique for every record, but I cannot trace any scheduled method
C. I tried to manually exit transaction before kafka start, but it ends with error:

ElasticApm.currentTransaction().end(); // added line
kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start();

How to solve the problem with these constraints:

have unique traceId and spanId for every kafka record
have autostartup = false (start kafka manually)
scheduled instrumentation is enabled


Has nothing to do with Spring for Apache Kafka.
